# Child Path Angular8

Tags: angular, components, angular-routerlink

I have created some components and paths. I have some child components also now what i have done is initially I will load my component logincomponent. and when u logged in ,two components one dashboard which is parent component and one child component alllleadcomponent inside dashboard will be render. which is working find.
Now I have created some links and when i click home it will redirect me to the logincomponent 
So **what i want is When i click on home link i want to render all leadcomponent instead of redirecting to logincomponent**
so here are my links

```
 <ul class="menulist">
            <li><a routerLink=""><mat-icon >home</mat-icon>Home</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="addlead"><mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>Add Lead</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="adduser"><mat-icon>person_add</mat-icon>Add User</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and here are app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes =[

  { 
    path:'dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent,
    children:[
      {path:'',component:AllleadsComponent},
      {path:'adduser',component:AdduserComponent},
      {path:'addlead',component:AddleadComponent},
      {path:'editLead',component:UpdateLeadComponent}
    ]
  },
  {path:'',component:LoginComponent}
]
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @NicholasK check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your router configuration setup, the only way you can navigate to the `AllleadsComponent` is by navigating to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard`.

You're getting directed to the `LoginComponent` because of the last object in your `appRoutes` array:

```
{path:'',component:LoginComponent}
```

This is telling the Angular router that when you navigate to `http://localhost:4200` you want the `LoginComponent` loaded.

To get what you want, change the html for your home button to this:

```
<li><a routerLink="/dashboard"><mat-icon >home</mat-icon>Home</a></li>
```